# Python - keeps reporting a syntax erro on the 'elif' statement

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer currently learning Python. While building the classic game 'Pong!', I encountered this problem in which Python keeps telling me that I have a syntax error on elif statement. However, I just couldn't find out where my problem is... Here is some of my code:

```
def draw(canvas):
    global score1, score2, pad1_pos, pad2_pos, ball_vel, RIGHT, c
        # update ball
    '''reflections on the left wall'''
    if (ball_pos[0] == BALL_RADIUS + PAD_WIDTH) and (ball_pos in [range(pad1_pos, pad1_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)]):
        print ball_pos
        ball_vel[0] = - ball_vel[1]
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1]
        c += 10

    '''scoring of paddle1'''
    elif (ball_pos[0] == BALL_RADIUS + PAD_WIDTH) and not (ball_pos in [range(pad1_pos, pad1_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)]):
        score2 += 1
        spawn_ball()
        RIGHT = False

    '''reflections on the right wall'''
    elif ball_pos[0] == (WIDTH - 1) - BALL_RADIUS - PAD_WIDTH and (ball_pos in [range(pad2_pos, pad2_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)]):
        '''remember how Python counts the values starting from 0'''
        '''the first pixel of a 600p wall is 0 and the last one is 599'''
        ball_vel[0] = - ball_vel[1]
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel [1]
        c += 10

    '''scoring of paddle2'''
    elif ball_pos[0] == (WIDTH - 1) - BALL_RADIUS - PAD_WIDTH and not (ball_pos in [range(pad2_pos, pad2_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)]):
        score1 += 1
        spawn_ball()
        RIGHT = True

    '''reflections on the upper wall'''
    elif ball_pos[1] == BALL_RADIUS:
        ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = - ball_vel[1]

    '''reflections on the bottom wall'''
    elif ball_pos[1] == (HEIGHT - 1) - BALL_RADIUS:
        ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = - ball_vel[1]
```

I didn't paste my complete draw function, but the problem appears right at my first elif statement saying: "Line 85: SyntaxError: bad input ('elif')". I have no idea where my syntax error is and the curious thing is that my if statement turns out to be fine. I am wondering if the content of my elif statement is valid since it's a fairly long one and as a beginner I tend to mess up with long codes...

By the way, what I'm trying to do here is basically determine when the ball should reflect and where should it be reflecting to. Therefore, I used the 'in' and 'range' statement to set the range of my paddles so that the ball will only reflect when it's hit on the paddles(in the range). I am not sure if that's the right way to do it and please let me know if I'm messing up with anything here. This is my very first question posted on stack over flow and I only did it after a thorough examination of my code. Sorry that the question turns out to be super long but I would truly appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that you should consider changing your single line comments to use the pound symbol. I ran your code and once I indented the multiline comments, the syntax error disappeared. As the other answers mentioned, following an `if statement`, the compiler expects either once-more indented code or an `elif statement` or new code at the same indentation-level as your `if`.

```
def draw(canvas):
    global score1, score2, pad1_pos, pad2_pos, ball_vel, RIGHT, c
        # update ball
    '''
    reflections on the left wall
    '''
    if (ball_pos[0] == BALL_RADIUS + PAD_WIDTH) and (ball_pos in [range(pad1_pos, pad1_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)]):
        print ball_pos
        ball_vel[0] = - ball_vel[1]
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1]
        c += 10

    elif (ball_pos[0] == BALL_RADIUS + PAD_WIDTH) and (ball_pos in [range(pad1_pos, pad1_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)]):
        print ball_pos
        ball_vel[0] = - ball_vel[1]
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1]
        c += 10

    elif ball_pos[0] == (WIDTH - 1) - BALL_RADIUS - PAD_WIDTH and (ball_pos in range(pad2_pos, pad2_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)):
        '''remember how Python counts the values starting from 0'''
        '''the first pixel of a 600p wall is 0 and the last one is 599'''
        ball_vel[0] = - ball_vel[1]
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel [1]
        c += 10

        '''scoring of paddle2'''
    elif ball_pos[0] == (WIDTH - 1) - BALL_RADIUS - PAD_WIDTH and not (ball_pos in range(pad2_pos, pad2_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)):
        score1 += 1
        spawn_ball()
        RIGHT = True

        '''reflections on the upper wall'''
    elif ball_pos[1] == BALL_RADIUS:
        ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = - ball_vel[1]

        '''reflections on the bottom wall'''
    elif ball_pos[1] == (HEIGHT - 1) - BALL_RADIUS:
        ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = - ball_vel[1]
```

Answer (score 6):

an `elif` can only come immediately after an `if` block or an `elif` block. You have a string constant `'''scoring of paddle1'''` in between your `if` and `elif`, so strictly speaking one doesn't immediately follow the other.

Consider changing your comments to use the pound symbol: `#scoring of paddle1`